# How to convert this Sql query to LINQ query

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql

can any one to help to convert this below given sql query to linq.

```
     exec sp_executesql N'use db;
            WITH Members AS
            (
                select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id DESC) as row, num
                from  tbl
            )
            Select row,  num
            from Members 
            where row BETWEEN  @InitialRow AND @EndRow order by row ASC;',N'@InitialRow int,@EndRow int',@InitialRow=0,@EndRow=5
```

--
thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to to it (with @InitialRow=0,@EndRow=5) :

```
var result = Members
               .OrderByDescending(x => x.id)
               .Take(5)
               .Select((x,i) => 
                   new { row = i, num = x.num });
```

With any values:

```
var result = Members
               .OrderByDescending(x => x.id)
               .Skip(InitialRow)
               .Take(EndRow-InitialRow)
               .Select((x,i) => 
                   new { row = i+InitialRow, num = x.num });
```

Comment: HI  thanks for the response, But  I am looking for re writting this query using linq.

Comment: Yes, that is what I did :)

Comment: This is LINQ using the extension method (lambda) syntax. @Hogan The query looks good except it should be OrderByDescending.

Comment: Thanks alot @Hogan ,@AnthonyChu for your time, unfortunatly I am getting one error.

LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[<>f__AnonymousType0`2[System.Int32,System.Nullable`1[System.Decimal]]] Select[members,<>f__AnonymousType0`2](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[members], System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`3[members,System.Int32,<>f__AnonymousType0`2[System.Int32,System.Nullable`1[System.Decimal]]]])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: Basically I am getting this error while binding this result to the datagrid.
datagrid1.Itemsource=result;

Comment: I think I had a typo, should have been `new { row = i, num = x.num });`  I changed the answer.